# Offset time cells by a value in Excel or Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a bunch of time cells in a spreadsheet. I'm trying to offset them all by a specific time interval, say 30 minutes or 1 hour. I don't want to offset these time values in cells elsewhere. I want the cells containing the old values to be replaced by the new values. Is there a way to do this?

PS: I use google sheets so would appreciate if you could give a solution with regards to that platform. Not an issue otherwise, I'll try to replicate the functionality myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can calculate them and overwrite (easiest) =A1+0.5/24 copied down if your data starts at A1. Otherwise you have to use scripts or VBA in Excel.

Comment: Even though you "don't want to offset these time values in cells elsewhere" that is the simplest way to get it done.  use a formula to offset them elsewhere, then paste special>Values Only those values over your originals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel, put `=30/60/24` or however many minutes it is you want to move them, in some other cell.
Then copy that cell, select the others, and do Paste Special | Values | Add.

GoogleSheets seems to not offer Values | Add within Paste Special.
So I guess you need to create temporary new cells being `=A1+30/60/24` (can be on a different sheet), and then copy those new ones, followed by Paste Special | Values only, back in the original cells.